# How do I combine these mysql statements

Tags: java, mysql, sql, resultset

I am currently doing this:

```
    SELECT SS.service_name , SS.id, SH.shortcode FROM smsc_app_db.service SS
 INNER JOIN shortcode SH ON SS.confirmation_shortcode = SH.id;

    SELECT count(service_id) FROM smsc_app_db.service_status 
where smsc_app_db.service_status.service_id = ?;
```

After running the first select, I get the result in java, then for each row of the ResultSet, I use the SS.ID value to
count the number of subscribers to that service on the service_status table (using the second statement)

But I would like to combine the 2 statements into one.

Is it possible to make the 
`select count(service_id)`

a column in the first select statement?

e.g. if the result of

`select count(service_id)....` is stored in `subscriber_base`

```
    SELECT SS.service_name , SS.id, SH.shortcode, subscriber_base FROM 
smsc_app_db.service SS INNER JOIN shortcode SH ON SS.confirmation_shortcode = SH.id;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`join` the service_status table to the existing query and aggregate to get the counts.

```
SELECT SS.service_name, SS.id, SH.shortcode, count(*) subscriber_base 
FROM smsc_app_db.service SS 
INNER JOIN shortcode SH ON SS.confirmation_shortcode = SH.id
INNER JOIN smsc_app_db.service_status sstat ON sstat.service_id = SS.id
GROUP BY SS.service_name, SS.id, SH.shortcode
```

Comment: Great answer. Please change the ON sstat.service_id = ss.id to               ON sstat.service_id = SS.id, so I can mark this as the correct answer thanks!!!

Comment: i don't think that would make any difference.

Comment: Come on, its because I tested it and it does, that's why I asked you to change it. I am using MariaDb on CentOS and trust me, it does.